# Controller Method not found in nesting laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, frameworks

I'm new in laravel and I got an error and don't really know how to fix it.
I got an error "Controller method not found" when i'm asking for this route : /projet/6/note

My routes.php

```
Route::controller('projet.note', 'NoteController');
Route::resource('/eleves', 'StudentController');
Route::controller('/auth', 'AuthController');
Route::resource('/user', 'UserController');
Route::resource('/projet', 'ProjectController');
Route::post('/eleves/search', 'StudentController@postSearch');
Route::resource('/classe', 'ClasseController');
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

I tried to type php artisan routes to see if the routes was working, and she's not.
I tried then to change controller into resource in the line about NoteController, the routes was there but when i go on the link, same error.

Then i guess i can't do 'projet/note' without that my NoteController is a resource?
It's a problem because i need to nest NoteController to ProjetController.

My only action in NoteController

```
public function getIndex($id)
{
    return View::make('note.noter')
        ->with('project', Project::find($id))
    ;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you plan to have more than this action in your NoteController? If not you could just add a route pointing directly to the action

Comment: Yes i'll have more tahn one action in the controller

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right. This is the best solution I could come up with:

```
Route::any('projet/{id}/note/{action?}', function($id, $action = 'index'){
    $controller = App::make('NoteController');
    $action = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']).studly_case($action);
    if(method_exists($controller, $action)){
        return $controller->callAction($action, [$id]);
    }
});
```

This basically does some similar things as `Route::controller`. First we create a controller instance, then build the action name out of the request method and the second parameter in the route and in the end, call the action (if it exists).